# posts.populate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate my post's author fields (which is are object ids) with the corresponding author objects which are in a separate collection.

My controller code is as follows:

```
exports.readPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find({ board: req.params.board });
    await posts.populate("author").execPopulate();
    res.send(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err.message);
  }
};
```

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working as I have very similar code in another controller method that is working just fine.

All help greatly appreciated.

Below is the relevant Model file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    content: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    comments: [
      {
        comment: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          trim: true,
        },
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now(),
        },
      },
    ],
    author: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    board: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Board",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

Comment: if the function works, you're simply missing the `posts = ` before `await`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`posts` is an array of models. `populate` must be called on a model. The preferred way to do this is at query time. It probably works on your other controller because you are using a `findOne` so it is returning the model, not the Array.

```js
const posts = Post
  .find({ board: req.params.board })
  .populate('author')
  .exec();
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam, yes the other controller method is only working with a single result. However I did already try your suggestion. The response from the server is:
Post.find(...).populate(...).execPopulate is not a function

Comment: oh! Sorry! I missread 'exec' as 'execPopulate', I never knew this method existed. Thank you. :)